# Ошибка Can't create table `magaz`.`products` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: laravel

Имею 2 таблицы - products и categories. Делаю миграцию - выдаёт эту ошибку, но всё же создаёт таблицу, до таблицы категорий дело не доходит.
products

```
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->text('des');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        });
    }
```

categories

```
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->string('name');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Причиной может быть порядок файлов миграций. Если миграция `products` происходит раньше чем миграция `categories`.

Comment: categories - `$table->bigIncrements('id');` => `$table->id();`. А потом включаем логику - сперва создаём таблицу products и добавляем связь?? какую? таблицы categories ещё нет. Тут или порядок смените, или связь добавлять надо в миграции где создаётся таблица categories